# Is it possible to call a function defined inside a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

In the following code, I can call baz. Also somewhere else I read "JavaScript has function-level scope". I know, Im confusing myself somewhere. Can somebody make me understand please?

```
/* An anonymous function used as a closure. */
var baz;
(function() {
    var foo = 10;
    var bar = 2;
    baz = function() { 
        return foo * bar; 
    };
})();

baz(); // baz can access foo and bar, even though it is executed outside of the
       // anonymous function
```

.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `baz` is declared outside the anonymous function (even if it isn't actually defined until you use the function expression to assign a value to it). This places its scope outside said function.

`foo` and `bar` are declared inside the anonymous function, which limits their scope to that function. The function assigned to `baz` can access them because they were in scope when it was created.

Answer (score 0):

David explained it pretty well. Things that are in scope where you define `baz`, are still available after your anonymous function has returned.

Read about [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) for more information.